# Django - Issue with parsing multiselect values received as request.GET context parameter to a template

Tags: django

I had passed request.GET as context parameter to my template. I am planning to use populate multiselect dropbox with the values coming from request.GET in the colony tag. I have passed the context correctly from views.py file but I am not able to fetch the all the colony values in template. If I use values.colony, I just get the last value in this list. I am using following code

views.py
'values': request.GET

I am using  value in values.getlist('colony') in the template file to retrieve all colony values but this line is giving error anytime I use values.getlist('colony'). Can you please suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please elaborate your question. This question does not show any research effort, it is unclear or not useful. Show us the exact value of request.GET.colony.